# comm not working to find unique words to file1 from two files

Tags: comm

I have two text files in which I have to use the comm command to extract all unique words from file 1. So just those that are not in file 2.
I was asked to use the `comm` command (not `diff` nor `join`).

I have tried a lot of things such as `comm -32 file1 file2`, but this returns all the words in file 1.

Comment: maybe your file1 contains only unique words? what's the input you are feeding?

Comment: No there are indeed words that are similar, I checked using grep.
'input you are feeding'? I'm comparing sorted lists of words. File1 contains 2574 words and file2 around 40 000 words, using the comm command I get the same list of words of file1, with 2574 words.

Comment: please provide excerpts of the two files that exhibit the problem. also check whether the files have different EOL-markers (e.g. CRLF vs LF)

Comment: I don't know those things sorry...

Comment: see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRLF). it basically boils down to your two files containing invisible characters that make two words differ even if they seem identical. you still haven't provided sample input for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

`comm` expects sorted files where each word has to be on one line (it's the full lines that are compared).

So it's

```
(export LC_ALL=C
comm -23 <(grep -Po '\S+' file1 | sort) <(grep -Po '\S+' file2 | sort))
```

(assuming GNU `grep` with PCRE support and a shell supporting process substitution like `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash`).

Fixing the locale to C to perform byte to byte comparison for `sort` and `comm`.

Comment: (export LC_ALL=C comm -23 <(grep -Po '\S+' tekst.txt | sort) <(grep -Po '\S+' woordenlijst.txt | sort))
-bash: export: `-23': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/dev/fd/63': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/dev/fd/62': not a valid identifier

Comment: @hdb004, that's 2 lines, the first one sets LC_ALL, the second calls `comm`. That's in a subshell for limiting the scope of the LC_ALL variable

Answer (score 0):

If one of your files came from a windows environment the line terminators may be different. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/419780) for conversions.